# Get Street Name and Apt number from Address

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Thanks for looking into my post, well I been scratching my head for a long time now the requirement which sound pretty simple turned out to be a tough one, below is the requirement....

I need to seprate (Street Number, Street Name, Suite\Apt information or any zip found)

Address looks like this:

1. 123 Main St
2. 123 NW.17 St
3. One Washington Way, Suite 405
4. 1 Governement Dr #400, Washington, 01211

So far I was able to seprate out 123 Main St, but whenever I go further using Char\Pat index in my string the address from above line 2 gets scramblled such as it becomes (123 NW St)

My main gole is to break htis string and put it in a table and then concatinate.....

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "So far I was able to..." but you didn't post what you've done to get that far. It's pretty difficult to say what you're doing wrong if you don't show us what you've done.

Answer (score 8):

Parsing addresses is a nightmare in my experience.  There are probably at least a dozen ways to represent the same address, and you will have a tough time coming up with a reliable way to pull the pieces appart.

My recommendation would be to pass any address you have to a mapping service (google, yahoo whatever) and use the results that they pass back to you.  Smarter people than you and I have found a very reliable way to do this.  I would recommend taking advantage of what they offer.

Comment: I see your point, but I do consider this an answer.  Sometimes the best answer is to take a totally different approach.

Comment: I agree that this is a solution. No amount of nested procedural code is going to give the OP a reliable answer. The answer is to outsource to someone who specialises in this stuff.

Comment: This is the only way to achieve the desired results.  The address will need to go through a standardization/parsing process.  From that you can pull out your required parts easily.  But to code one up yourself will be a project in it's own.

Answer (score -3):

Well , This is my alternative suggestion not a answer of your question.

String manipulation operation is always very critical and tedious job and many time it’s not work perfectly.

I have very good one alternative option which you would like to prefer. 
Instead of having single line address is better to divide into different part.

e.g. 
street1
street2
city
state
country

Now in database you can create XML datatype and store all above field into one in XML format field like

```
<Address>
    <street1>data1</street1>
    <street2>data2</street2>
    <city>data3</city>
    <state>data4</state>
    <country>data5</country>
</Address>
```

Advantage of this :

1.Now you are flexible to insert and retrieve data if user don’t want to enter any field  or you don’t want display any field then this is best way to do .
2.It will give you good performance as well because XML Parsing is faster than String manipulation.
3.XML return more accuracy than string operation.

Comment: He would still have to parse the data in order to get it into this format.  What would be the advantage of having a single XML column as opposed to a column for each piece of the address?

Comment: ok if he divide address into different column that this is fine so there are no any operation require but if we see in database so there will be many column for one single address . I have suggested XML because after parsing it will return accurate result where string operation is not that much accurate. In SQL Server XML Parsing is fast than string manipulation.

Comment: Hrrm, I think something might have been lost in translation on that one.  If you are suggesting it would be easier to parse XML than it would be to parse a string I agree.  But I would still argue that it makes more sense to hold each piece of the address in it's own column rather than trying to put it all in a single XML column.

Comment: I agree with you that having different column is better rather than XML or String operation but this is my alternative If he don't want to create multiple columns in database.

Comment: One more thing, In future when address require some more extra field e.g. PostalCode, Phone Number at that time to add one simple tag in XML is better than to change structure of database. I hope you agree with this !

Comment: It seems more work parsing data from XML to the report. There is RDBMS for the reason.